# Inheritance in C#: when and when not to override a function to intentionally throw a "not supported" exception?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I created a generic repository (abstract class) that has Create, Update, and Delete functions.

```
public abstract class GenericRepo<T> where T : class
{
     public virtual Task CreateAsync(T entity){ // not shown };
     public virtual Task UpdateAsync(T entity){ // not shown };
     public virtual Task DeleteAsync(T entity){ // not shown };
}
```

I would be implementing-inheriting this abstract class but not all concrete repos will use all three. For example, I have StatusLog entity that can only be created, not updated, and not deleted:

```
public class StatusLogRepo : GenericRepo<StatusLog>
{
     public override Task UpdateAsync(StatusLog statusLog)
     {
           throw new NotSupportedException();
     }

     public override Task DeleteAsync(StatusLog statusLog)
     {
           throw new NotSupportedException();
     }
}
```

I see some other people's code approach this issue the same way as above, but I find it quite dirty and unsettling. I could also not override the classes and hope that the Delete and Update functions will not ever be called. That's bad, too. Multiple inheritance comes to mind, but that isn't supported in C#.

So two questions:

1. When is it appropriate to override a function in order to declare it as "not supported" if ever it were called?
2. Assuming that the answer to #1 is "never appropriate" or even "highly recommended that I stay away from that approach", how can I restructure my code base so that I will not have to copy-paste identical code for every single concrete Repo that might need the same Create, Update, or Delete routines?

Comment: And what your GenericRepo implementations (mark as not shown) do?

Comment: What are all the combinations of up-to-three methods that might be available?

Comment: @Evk - I marked "not shown" because they are not relevant to the issue. It can be reading/writing files to disk, or database access. Whatever the storage implementation at the GenericRepo level, its derived classes would also use them automatically.

Comment: @RichardIrons - not sure what you're asking, but there can be be a total of 6 configurations for a concrete repository that would allow/disallow each of Create, Update, and Delete. For example, there might be one that disallows updating only, like a thumbs up on a blog post.

Comment: @mickael-caruso - I'm asking in case there's an obvious hierarchy. Are there any that don't allow Create, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

> When is it appropriate to override a function in order to declare it as "not supported" if ever it were called?

This is appropriate in rare cases when a method that you must override is optional, according to the logic of your design. In situations like this you need to provide a way for the caller to *not* call your optional method, for example:

```
[Flags]
enum SupportedOperations {
    Read   = 1
,   Create = 2
,   Update = 4
,   Delete = 8
}

public abstract class GenericRepo<T> where T : class {
     public virtual SupportedOperations SupportedOps {
         get {
             return 0; // Nothing is supported by default
         }
     }
     public virtual Task CreateAsync(T entity) {
         throw new NotSupportedException();
     }
     public virtual Task UpdateAsync(T entity) {
         throw new NotSupportedException();
     }
     public virtual Task DeleteAsync(T entity) {
         throw new NotSupportedException();
     }
}
```

This approach lets the caller ensure that an operation is supported by checking the appropriate flag of `SupportedOps` prior to making a call that may throw `NotSupportedException`.

> Multiple inheritance comes to mind, but that isn't supported in C#.

A combination of interfaces and extension methods let you come pretty close to it. Rather than using an abstract class and inheriting default implementations, create several interfaces, and provide shared implementations as extension methods. This approach lets you build shallow hierarchies that behave in a way similar to multiple inheritance.